# How to Set StartDate Every Month Is Change

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

i want to ask here i have a datepicker, in there i want to set up my datepicker if everytime i change the month on datepicker, the start date will always from the 22nd and the date end will always on last number of the month .

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var currentTime = new Date();
  // First Date Of the month 
  var startDateFrom = new Date(currentTime.getFullYear(), currentTime.getMonth(), 22);
  // Last Date Of the Month 
  var startDateTo = new Date(currentTime.getFullYear(), currentTime.getMonth() + 1, 0);
  var date_input = $('#date'); //our date input has the name "date"
  var container = $('.bootstrap-iso form').length > 0 ? $('.bootstrap-iso form').parent() : "body";
  date_input.datepicker({
    startDate: "today",
    format: 'mm/dd/yyyy',
    container: container,
    todayHighlight: true,
    autoclose: true,
    startDate: startDateFrom,
    endDate: startDateTo
  })
})
```

```html
<link href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<input class="form-control" id="date" placeholder="MM/DD/YYY" name="date_create" />
```

if iam using my code its will only suggest me on this current month and i cant change the month like what i needed.

Can anyone give me a solution what should I change so the code I create works?

iam using [here](http://eternicode.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker)

Comment: Which datepicker are you using? There are several of them

Comment: iam using http://eternicode.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker/

Comment: where are referencing to the datepicker library you mentioned (eternicode.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker) ?